# SocialEnginePHP get module's folder name

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

How to find the name of my module's folder name in SocialEnginePHP(*built on Zend framework)?

```
\application\modules\MyModule\widgets\somewidget\index.tpl
```

In "somewidget\index.tpl" I need to be able to echo "MyModule" that is the name of the module's folder. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

well dont know about the `socialengine` but,
as you are saying it is built in zend framework, so you can use,

```
$module = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getModuleName() ;
```

in zf it'll give the name of the module, and as often the case the name of the folder will be same.

Comment: Seems to get the name of a module, but it is getting the name of the "core" module and not my module. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: it is returning name as application ? it considers modules only which falls under module directory, like application, album, etc..

Comment: It returns just "core", that being the name of the Core module in SocialEngine.

Comment: Actually, I think this is not getting the name of the folder the module is in. It looks like it is getting some name inside from the module.

Comment: well i have used it in zend and it returns the module name, as i said i have no idea for `socialengine` , it was just a suggestion, i hope someone will provide you the answer you are looking for.. !